# Android how to create a JSON file in SDCARD?

Tags: android

I need help on creating a new JSON file to the SDCARD, i get the FileNotFoundException while trying to load, and i now how to read the file but only if it's already constructed.

How can i manage to create a new JSON file in the SDCARD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to add permission to your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Then, write the code as in JAVA.

The path to your sdcard is :

```
String dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"nameOfYourFile.extension"
```

To create Json string, the best way is to use the class JSONObject and JSONArray.